# How to check if a certain value is existent or if it exists twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So i have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID  CUR_Valid
1   N 
1   N
1   N
1   N
1   N
1   Y
2   N
2   N
2   Y
3   Y
```

So as you can see one ID can only be allowed to have one y. I want to write a statment that shows me the IDs that have no Y or more then one Y.

My code so far looks like this:

```
Select [BILL_ID]
      ,[Bill_MONTH]
      ,[CUR_VALID]
      ,COUNT(CUR_VALID)
FROM DB.dbo.table
WHERE CUR_VALID = 'Y'
GROUP BY [BILL_ID]
      ,[Bill_MONTH]
      ,[CUR_VALID]
 Having COUNT(CUR_VALID) > 1 OR COUNT(CUR_VALID) <1
```

I'm not sure whats wrong. Can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this answer. Hope this helps you:

```
Select [BILL_ID]
      ,[Bill_MONTH]
      ,[CUR_VALID]
      ,COUNT(CUR_VALID)
FROM DB.dbo.table
--WHERE CUR_VALID = 'Y'
GROUP BY [BILL_ID]
      ,[Bill_MONTH]
      ,[CUR_VALID]
 Having COUNT(CASE WHEN CUR_VALID = 'Y' THEN 1 END) > 1 OR COUNT(CASE WHEN CUR_VALID = 'Y' THEN 1 END) <1
```

When you put `WHERE CUR_VALID = 'Y'` condition, it remove the records which don't have the the Y.

Try this update for, number of IDs.

```
Select COUNT(1)[No of Ids]
FROM DB.dbo.table
GROUP BY [BILL_ID]
      ,[Bill_MONTH]
      ,[CUR_VALID]
 Having COUNT(CASE WHEN CUR_VALID = 'Y' THEN 1 END) > 1 OR COUNT(CASE WHEN CUR_VALID = 'Y' THEN 1 END) <1
```

It returns the Number of Ids.

Comment: Good Answer:) It seems right but it isent possible. The result shows me Thousends of results. Is it possible to just create one number that shows me how many Ids have no y or 2 y?

Comment: Yeah, we can use <> 1. I just correct the error in his Query.

Comment: Oke I just did some more testing and found out that when for example [No of IDs] is 7 that there are just 7 N. So this Query still acually only gives me what i already know. Well I'm going to try out some more things

Comment: Okey got it Having COUNT(CASE WHEN CUR_VALID = 'Y' THEN 1 END) > 1 OR COUNT(CASE WHEN CUR_VALID = 'N' THEN 1 END) <1

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SQL Aliases
```

Count as totalValid

```
Select [BILL_ID]
          ,[Bill_MONTH]
          ,[CUR_VALID]
          ,COUNT(CUR_VALID) as totalValid
    FROM DB.dbo.table
    WHERE CUR_VALID = 'Y'
    GROUP BY [BILL_ID]
          ,[Bill_MONTH]
          ,[CUR_VALID]
     Having  totalValid > 1 OR  totalValid <1
```

Comment: this wont work when something does not have a Y will it? totalvalid will always be at least 1

Comment: It  will give you a non-zero value if Y already exists in the database. If it doesn't exist, then you will get zero.

Comment: seriously test your logic. if you filter out Id of 5, status of N, how can you get a count of 0. you filtered it out before you count it... it has dissappeared... and why not just do a <> 1 as opposed to an or

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample query that demonstrates the identification of one with no Y or one with two or more Y's

```
with dat
as
(
select 1 id,'N' cur_valid  union all 
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'Y' union all
select 2,'N' union all
select 2,'N' union all
select 2,'Y' union all
select 3,'Y' union all
select 4,'Y' union all /* two Ys */
select 4,'Y' union all
select 5,'N' /* no Y */)
select id
from
(
   select id,sum(case when cur_valid='Y' then 1 else 0 end) x
   from dat
   group by id
) ilv
where x<>1
```

this can be condensed to

```
with dat
as
(
select 1 id,'N' cur_valid  union all 
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'N' union all
select 1,'Y' union all
select 2,'N' union all
select 2,'N' union all
select 2,'Y' union all
select 3,'Y' union all
select 4,'Y' union all /* two Ys */
select 4,'Y' union all
select 5,'N' /* no Y */)
select id
from dat
group by id
having sum(case when cur_valid='Y' then 1 else 0 end)<>1
```

Comment: especially the second solution is really nice +1

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use self join like this

```
select d1.id, count(d2.id)
from (select id from dat group by id) d1
left join dat d2 on d1.id = d2.id and d2.cur_valid = 'Y'
group by d1.id
having count(d2.id) <> 1
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=152b0b803b9ac6c3306f9b3fe7908ff3) - thanks @Abbennett for the data

Comment: cheeky, i spent 5 minutes typing that with statement out:)